# CF8 installation error in Mac OsX using terminal

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to install CF8 using the binary file on my mac (Mountain Lion 10.8.4) from the terminal.

While I run the .app file it says 'Cannot run application because powerPC applications are no more supported'

I dd change he permissions on the file. But as the installer fires up and after few seconds i get the below errors:

```
./coldfusion-801-lin64.bin: line 2479: /tmp/install.dir.36216/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
./coldfusion-801-lin64.bin: line 2479: /tmp/install.dir.36216/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: Undefined error: 0
```

I am an admin user. The version of Apache is: 2.2.22.

I am aware that adobe does not support CF8 anymore so they are throwing a blind eye.

After hours of googling i found the CF8 installer from here. The dmg failed to run and hence moved to the binary version. :http://www.dcepler.net/post.cfm/last-day-to-download-cf-8-and-9-from-adobe-with-verity

Comment: Linux applications don't run on Mac OS X. Try downloading the correct application.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.The issue was the binary file was meant for snow leapord or lower version.